# Sed construct populate list of keys with the environment value of that key

Tags: bash, sed

I have a list of keys in a FILE:

```
FOO
BAR
BAZ
```

I am trying to construct a sed command to replace each line with:

```
FOO=$FOO
BAR=$BAR
BAZ=$BAZ
```

Where the right hand side is the value of the env variable with that name. For example, setting the environment variables:

```
export FOO=1
export BAR=2
export BAZ=3
```

After running sed, the FILE should be:

```
FOO=1
BAR=2
BAZ=3
```

I have tried these:

- `sed -i 's/^\(.*\)$/\1=$\1/g'`
- `sed -i "s/^\(.*\)$/\1=$\1/g"`
- `sed -i s/^\(.*\)$/\1="$\1"/g'`

And a few other variations. The issue is clearly in how the capture group is escaped, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Does it _have to_ be sed? Use awk. Or python.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't, awk is fine. I'd rather not use python.

Comment: Then use python, you'll be done in no time. Literally `python -c 'for line in sys.stdin: print(line "=" os.getenv(line));`

Comment: `The issue is clearly in how the capture group is escaped` How is it clear? Sed works on _text_, it does not replace `$anything` sequences to values.

Comment: 'Clearly' inasmuch as the capture works, the adding of the `=` works, it's just the expansion of the variable from $NAME to VALUE is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access environment variables in sed in the ways you are trying but it is quite simple with awk:

```
awk '{ print $0 in ENVIRON ? $0"="ENVIRON[$0] : $0 } FILE >FILE.new \
&& mv FILE.new FILE || { echo oops; rm FILE.new; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*/echo "&=$&"/e' file
```

Use the match back reference `&` and the `e` evaluation flag on the substitution command.